# Relationship between “from-WGS” and “to-WGS” transformation parameter

Tags: coordinate-system, trimble

I have some official Parameter for 3D Helmert transformation in direction “from-WGS”. Using the same in the other direction with just changing the sign of them, gives about 5cm difference.

Trimble Coordinate System manager recalculates those parameter – the values itself are slightly different than starting one, and using those parameter in transformation in “to-WGS” direction, differences are under 1cm.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to recalculate the “from-WGS” into “to-WGS” parameters?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.iogp.org/pubs/373-07-2.pdf, page 132, there are two methods of coordinate transformation: `Position Vector Transformation` and `Coordinate Frame Rotation`. Both differ in the sign of the rotation parameters. So you have to be sure what method is applicable for your parameter set.

Apart from that, you will get a non-zero height value when transforming from a different ellipsoid to WGS84. You have to use the same height to transform back, otherwise you will end up on a different spot horizontally.